# GCP Not able to create bucket with compute engine default service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine, gcp-iam

I have created a VM instance with compute engine default service account. 'I am not able to create a bucket from this VM using
`gsutil mb gs://bucketname` 
The command gives AccessDeniedException: 403 Access denied
Since the default compute engine service account has editor role with

- storage.buckets.create
- storage.buckets.delete
- storage.buckets.list permissions

why am I not able to create a bucket ?

Checked that the default service account had roles/editor role assigned and that the roles/editor had storage.create permissions

Comment: Review the Compute Engine Access Scopes. The default is storage read-only.